# Can I make two change event listeners fire each other?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, onchange

Is it possible to have one change also fire another change event and vice versa so that they work together?

```js
    /* Filter function LANGUAGE */
    $('input[type=radio][name=languagefilter]').change(function() {
      $language = this.value;
      $(".standardtaskcheckboxwrapper").hide();
      $(".standardtaskcheckboxwrapper." + $language).show();
    });

    /* Filter function CATEGORYTYPE */
    $('input[type=radio][name=associateddomain]').change(function() {
      $dataCatType = $(this).attr('data-cat-type');
      console.log($dataCatType);
      $(".standardtaskcheckboxwrapper").hide();
      $(".standardtaskcheckboxwrapper." + $dataCatType).show();
      $(".standardtaskcheckboxwrapper." + 'all').show();
    });
```

The HTML for this is something like this:

```html
<div>
  <div class="standardtaskcheckboxwrapper nl cat-1"></div>
  <div class="standardtaskcheckboxwrapper nl cat-2"></div>
  <div class="standardtaskcheckboxwrapper nl cat-3"></div>
  <div class="standardtaskcheckboxwrapper nl cat-4"></div>
  <div class="standardtaskcheckboxwrapper de cat-1"></div>
  <div class="standardtaskcheckboxwrapper de cat-2"></div>
  <div class="standardtaskcheckboxwrapper de cat-3"></div>
  <div class="standardtaskcheckboxwrapper en cat-1"></div>
  <div class="standardtaskcheckboxwrapper en cat-2"></div>
  <div class="standardtaskcheckboxwrapper en cat-3"></div>
  <div class="standardtaskcheckboxwrapper en cat-4"></div>
</div>`
```

The problem that I have now is that when you select in the category radio `cat-3` it filters correctly but when you then also set the language to for instance `nl` it will show all categories associated with the `nl`. I know that this is correct behavior for the way the code is now but I don't know how to adapt it so that both filters work together. Thanks everyone for helping me!

Comment: Please update the snippet I made you to a [mcve] - we need your radios

Comment: can you little more specific about what you want exactly? or update your snippet as your asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just chain them together and remove the duplicate line `$(".standardtaskcheckboxwrapper").hide();` like this:

```
$('input[type=radio][name=languagefilter], input[type=radio][name=associateddomain]').change(function() {

  $language = this.value;
  $(".standardtaskcheckboxwrapper").hide();
  $(".standardtaskcheckboxwrapper." + $language).show();

  $dataCatType = $(this).attr('data-cat-type');
  console.log($dataCatType);
  $(".standardtaskcheckboxwrapper." + $dataCatType).show();
  $(".standardtaskcheckboxwrapper." + 'all').show();

});
```

Comment: I did not know you can chain stuff. That is awesome! I am going to try this out.

Comment: I need to wait a bit before I can do that but I definitely will.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('input[type=radio][name=languagefilter]').change(function() {
 filter()
});
$('input[type=radio][name=associateddomain]').change(function() {
  filter()
});

function filter(){
  $language = $('input[name=languagefilter]:checked').val();
  $dataCatType = $('input[name=associateddomain]:checked').val();
  $language=$language ? "."+ $language :"";
  $dataCatType=$dataCatType ? "."+ $dataCatType:""
  $(".standardtaskcheckboxwrapper").hide();
  $($language + $dataCatType).show();
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="languagefilter" value="nl">n1
<input type="radio" name="languagefilter" value="de">de
<input type="radio" name="languagefilter" value="en">en

<input type="radio" name="associateddomain" value="cat-1">cat1
<input type="radio" name="associateddomain" value="cat-2">cat2
<input type="radio" name="associateddomain" value="cat-3">cat3
<input type="radio" name="associateddomain" value="cat-4">cat4


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="standardtaskcheckboxwrapper nl cat-1">1</div>
  <div class="standardtaskcheckboxwrapper nl cat-2">2</div>
  <div class="standardtaskcheckboxwrapper nl cat-3">3</div>
  <div class="standardtaskcheckboxwrapper nl cat-4">4</div>
  <div class="standardtaskcheckboxwrapper de cat-1">5</div>
  <div class="standardtaskcheckboxwrapper de cat-2">6</div>
  <div class="standardtaskcheckboxwrapper de cat-3">7</div>
  <div class="standardtaskcheckboxwrapper en cat-1">8</div>
  <div class="standardtaskcheckboxwrapper en cat-2">9</div>
  <div class="standardtaskcheckboxwrapper en cat-3">10</div>
  <div class="standardtaskcheckboxwrapper en cat-4">11</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ow your answer looks also very interesting. Let me test this one out as well.

Comment: Sorry but it does not seem to work. Selecting nl and cat4 should only return 4 it is returning 1,2,3,4,11

Comment: you want and operator rather than or okey  updating now

Comment: Yes I think I need the and operator instead of or. But am I mistaking that I can't find the or in the current snippit?

Comment: Really nice it works perfectly in the snippit. Sadly when I use the code I get a Unexpected Identifier. So I have some work to do ;-)